# Can't ping server, disconnects periodically

Tags: networking, ping, webserver

So I changed the static IP of my server and now i can't ping it from beyond the ISPs gateway. (I have two IP's assigned to me.) if i ping it's public, static IP address from my other IP address everything works fine*. if i try to ping from Who.is i get 100% loss. Here's the traceroute from me to it. (not sure what 70.65.32.1 address is as my public ip is 70.65.193.243. 184.71.51.46 is the static)

```
  1     *       <1 ms    <1 ms  hitronhub.home [192.168.0.1]
  2    14 ms    13 ms     8 ms  INTEL_CE_LINUX [70.65.32.1]
  3    11 ms     9 ms     8 ms  INTEL_CE_LINUX [184.71.51.46]

Trace complete.
```

*Now this might be related, it keeps the connection for about 10 -25 minutes before i can't access it at all for another 10 minutes. during this time the activity light on the network card, for the server is still flashing away. Any suggestions on how to resolve this? might be useful to know what the OS is Debian 8.6 running Plesk Onyx

Comment: Do you have firewall?

Comment: What setup are you actually running with? Your partial `traceroute` looks like your server is on your LAN and your router just answers? if you changed your static LAN IP for the server did you change the configuration for your router accordingly? What activity light on which card?

Comment: The modem is acting as a DHCP server (it's a Wi-Fi/Modem combo) for the my switch. The Modem allows for IP Pass through. So the Server is connected to the Modem on a pass through port. the Static IP on the server is one assigned from the ISP, the IP pass through means that the "router"side of the modem doesn't touch that port and therefore can not be configured on the modem as you mention. The light i refer to is the activity light on the network card, on the server. I bring it up because i believe that if this were an issue with the card the light shouldn't be indicating activity.

Comment: As for the firewall, Plesk manages the firewall (the IP has been updated in Plesk) But Plesk has seemed to have moved the settings for the firewall and i am currently hunting down those settings

Comment: Found the firewall settings pretty much everything is allowed through.
https://goo.gl/cqU86V